# que fórmula faço para intervalos de valores no excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, fórmula

Preciso de uma fórmula no excel que identifique intervalos, ex

```
0-30  = 20%
31-60 = 98,5%
61-90 = 100%
91-120 = 101,5%
```

se `f2<= 30` informar `20%;` se `f2>30` e `<60` informar `98,5%`, etc

Como faço?

Answer (score 2):

Minha resposta está um pouco atrasada, porém espero que seja útil.
Poderia substituir a função `SE` pela `PROCV`, da seguinte maneira:

```
=PROCV(c1;A1:B4;2;1);
```

Sendo que a tabela deve ser montada da seguinte forma:

[image: tabela]

Obs: como você informou intervalos de números inteiros apenas estou considerando que não haverá números decimais (p.ex. 30,2 - nesse caso não funcionaria).

Answer (score 1):

Se você tiver o Excel 2016, você pode usar a função `IFS`

```
=IFS(C1<=30,0.2,AND(C1>30,C1<=60),0.985,AND(C1>60,C1<=90),1,AND(C1>90,C1<=120),1.015,TRUE,"")
```

ou

```
=IFS(C1<=30,0.2,E(C1>30,C1<=60),0.985,E(C1>60,C1<=90),1,E(C1>90,C1<=120),1.015,Verdadeiro,""
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Acabei de fazer uma aqui, não sei se adequa ao que vc pretende fazer, mais a formula funciona no mesmo raciocínio do que foi solicitado.

Fórmula:

```
=SE(F2<30;"20%";SE((F2>=30)*OU(F2<61);"98,5%";SE((F2>=61)*OU(F2<91);"100%";"101,5%")))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a função "SE" (ou "IF" se seu office estiver em inglês).
Esta função tem o seguinte formato:
SE( "condição"; A; B)
onde A é a resposta caso a condição seja verdadeira e B é a resposta caso a condição seja falsa.

Exemplo:
SE(F2<=30; 20%; 100%)
Neste caso se o conteúdo da célula F2 for menor ou igual a 30, a fórmula retornará o valor 20%, caso contrário retornará 100%.

Para resolver seu problema, devemos utilizar várias vezes a mesma fórmula, uma dentro da outra, conforme abaixo:

```
SE(F2<=30; 20%; SE(F2<=60; 98,5%; SE(F2<=90; 100%; 101,5%)))
```

Perceba que caso F2<=30 (menor ou igual a 30) retorna 20%, portanto o próximo teste não precisa verificar se F2 é maior que trinta e menor OU igual a 60, pois ele já está sendo realizado somente quando F2 maior que 30.

Caso o resultado apareça como 0,2 ao invés de 20%, apenas utilize formatação da célula como sendo porcentagem (ícone % da barra de formatações).

Espero que tenha ficado clara a resposta.
Abraço.

Answer (score 0):

[[image: Utililzando a função SE com mais uma condição E [1]]

Utilizando a função SE com a condição E, você consegue nomear os intervalos.

Segue a fórmula;

```
=SE(E(B3>=0;B3<=30);$H$3;SE(E(B3>=31;B3<=60);$H$4;SE(E(B3>=61;B3<=90);$H$5;SE(E(B3>=91;B3<=120);$H$6))))
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/278411#) a sua resposta e compartilhe a fórmula como texto para facilitar a leitura :)

Comment: Valeu pela dica, Rafa, já ajustei! ;)